# Ia there any way to lock just a single app on my S6?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I want to lock just one app for a set period of time on my S6 daily. Where it will remain locked even  after restarting the phone and also automatically lock an app at a specific time.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes try downloading app lock pro from playstore.

Comment: Since it's a very generic name, could you add a link to the particular app? That way, people know which one you're recommending. Also, your recommendation is more useful if you can say more about how you've used this app and why you recommend it.